# Nested LinkedHashMap with large data is too slow

Tags: java, optimization

I have to implemented a table with the help of LinkedHashMap which has 1000000 rows and 450 column. I have done this using nested the LinkedHashMap. First I hash to a row and then column to find a particular cell.
My has values are Strings. 
Main problem is that it's running two slow and taking too much memory.
Is there any alternative way to solve implement this.

Here is the code that I have implemeted..

```
public LinkedHashMap<String,Row> transitionTable;

// This class represent the one Row of Transition Table
public class Row implements Cloneable{

    // This represent the tagCount of a Row
    LinkedHashMap<String,Float> tagCount;
        float totalOccurance=0f;

    //Constructor
    public Row()
    {
        tagCount=new LinkedHashMap<String,Float>();
    }

    // Method used to do cloning of
    public Object Clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        Row row=new Row();
        row.tagCount = (LinkedHashMap<String, Float>)this.tagCount.clone();
        return row;
    }
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: what are you using `LinkedHashMap`? Do you want to maintain the insertion order as well?

Comment: do the sorting in database instead of memory.

Comment: I have also tried with HashMap but found no improvement....... this table is required so frequent in future that it's not good to keep this table in hard disk.

Comment: what are your java heap settings? can your machine allocate more memory for your java application?

Comment: yes java heap size is 1500m... I have increased it in netbeans id for my project...

Answer (score 0):

We have a system, where we store around 10000+ records of a table in memory using [Radix Tree Implementation](https://code.google.com/p/radixtree/), from which we can search data pretty fast.